# Removing double quotes from all values in CSV file before upload in S3

Tags: python-3.x, csv, quotes

I am trying to read a CSV file stored on S3 using Athena. Unfortunately Athena does not allow me to run my queries correctly since all values in the CSV files are enclosed with double quotes. Can someone please suggest me the workaround this problem.

I am familiar using Python as a programming language if I have to use that clean this file. It is a 7 GB file

Comment: You should follow this link https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/basics.html

Comment: Can you please guide me a little bit more in detail

Comment: import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df.applymap(lambda x: x.replace('"', ''))

Here a is your actual data